# JSON nested list is null in ASP.NET POST controller

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller like this:

```
<HttpPost> Function InputCommand(Input As List(Of KeyValueClass(Of String, Object))
End Function
```

when i send a request with this json as body:

```
{
  "Input": [
      {
        "Key": "CardCode",
        "Value": 969
      },
      {
        "Key": "PersonID",
        "Value": 3
      },
      {
        "Key": "LinkedIDs",
        "Value": [
          {
            "Key": "SubscriptionID",
            "Value": 1
          }
        ]
      },
  ]
}
```

All the objects with a primitive value are deserialized and retrieved as expected, except the LinkedIDs value which is retrieved  as `{Object}`.

I tried custom binders but couldn't get it to work

I expect the LinkedIDs to get parsed as a `List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)` or similar

Comment: What .NET/ASP version are you using? What are you using as JSON serializer?

Comment: Asp.net 4.8
The serialization is done client side via JSON.Stringify

Comment: I meant server-side. Try using `KeyValueClass(Of String, JToken)`  if you are using Newtonsoft Json.NET